# Refactoring object into a flat array

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this.

```
{Brunch: 2, Kimchi: 1}
```

I need to refactor it into an an array/object

```
[{
"label" : "Brunch",
"value" : 2
},
{
"label" : "Kimchi",
"value" : 1
}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()` and `map()` to get desired result.

```js
var obj = {
  Brunch: 2,
  Kimchi: 1
}

var result = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) {
  return {
    "label": k,
    "value": obj[k]
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Cheers man - sure I've asked this before - not always something I see a lot of

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
var result = Object.keys(input).map(key => ({
    label: key,
    value: input[key],
}));
```